# MongoMapper default values and simple_form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, simple-form

I have a [Character model](https://github.com/vrinek/Dungeons-and-Dragons-on-Rails/blob/master/app/models/character.rb) which has some defaults and have created a [simple form for it](https://github.com/vrinek/Dungeons-and-Dragons-on-Rails/blob/master/app/views/non_player_characters/_form.html.erb) (or rather a subclass of the Character model) all tied together by a [controller](https://github.com/vrinek/Dungeons-and-Dragons-on-Rails/blob/master/app/controllers/non_player_characters_controller.rb).

The problem is that the form does not get the default values when called by `simple_form_for Character.new`.

Have I missed some configuration flag I need to set or do I have to edit the simple_form templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an open pull request for this issue: https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/393
so you should wait a bit before it will be merged :)
BTW, it's not a `SimpleForm` issue but rails `form_for`.